# Is there any downside of using for Proxy Jump using Public keys

Tags: ssh, openssh, public-key

I am trying to implement a Proxy jump between the client and server.

I am going through openssh server 8.9 documentation and did not find much information on usage and future problems using jump host using public keys.

I found from the documentation https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyJump

> Setting this option will cause ssh(1) to connect to the target host by first making a ssh(1) connection to the specified ProxyJump host and then establishing a TCP forwarding to the ultimate target from there.

My Topology

All The authorized_keys are established between random client, jump host and server

```
Random client --> Linux jump host (ubuntu) --> linux host server (ubuntu)
```

The admin will create a user in jump host when he wants to connect server and will be deleted after the usage, similarly, he will establish the public keys between the jump host user and Linux server.

`NOTE: Only one client will be logged in at a time, others will not allow if anyone logged in`

1. How to handle if the same client wants to connect frequently?
2. Is there best approach to copy authorized_keyes between these users.